# Why ES6 Imported Object's Child Return Undefined?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import, module

This is my code:

```
import * as _routes from '../../routes'
console.log('parent:', _routes)
console.log('child:', _routes.breadcrumb)
```

And this is the result:

[image: the result]

If `_routes` returning an object with `breadcrumb` as one of the child,
why `_routes.breadcrumb` returning `undefined`?

Comment: Most likely, `breakcrumb` is `undefined` at the time you logged it, and gets set later. I'd guess that you have a dependency cycle in your module graph.

Comment: You would need to resolve the dependency cycle. Imports run one at a time, so you are likely seeing this because whatever file calls `import * as _routes from '../../routes';` is _also_ imported by `routes` or something else it imports, so `breadcrumb` hasn't had time to run yet because we're still at the point of running the imports for that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind.

Based on @loganfsmyth's comment, most likely, the `breadcrumb` is `undefined` at the time `console.log` fired, and gets set later. Something like delay. So I just use `setTimeout` classic hack.

```
import * as _routes from '../../routes'
console.log('parent:', _routes)

setTimeout(function(){
  console.log('child:', _routes.breadcrumb)
}, 100)
```

It's temporary solution, but better than nothing.
Still don't know what exactly the issue was, so if anyone have explaination, please share. Thank you.